# How to publish ipa which is produced with xcodebuild build command

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, publish

I am creating an iOS application and I use `xcodebuild build ...` to build my project and `xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication ...` to create the ipa. When I try to publish the ipa to the App Store i get the following error:

> ERROR ITMS-90668: "Invalid Bundle Executable. The executable file 'Project.app/Project' contains incomplete bitcode.

I found that there is a solution for this problem - set `Enable Bitcode` to `No`. But this is not what I am looking for because if I create new project to the workspace I need to set this option to No for the new project as well because the default value is `Yes`.

Is there another solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out that when I use `xcodebuild build ...` **and** the `Enable Bitcode` is set to `Yes` the `-fembed-bitcode-marker` is added in the `OTHER_CFLAGS` for the clang. This flag just adds a "bitcode placeholder" instead of the full bitcode. This is done by Apple because the generation of the bitcode could slow down the build. To generate the full bitcode the `-fembed-bitcode-marker` must be replaced with `-fembed-bitcode`.

After creating ipa with the full bitcode I was able to publish my application to the App Store.

Another solution to my problem is to use `xcodebuild archive ...` instead of `xcodebuild build ...` to build my project and `xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath <path to the .xcarchive> ...` instead of `xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication ...` to create my ipa. When using the archive method the `-fembed-bitcode-marker` is automatically replaced with `-fembed-bitcode` and my ipa contains binaries with full bitcode.